# Easy way to "inherit" Bash completion

Tags: bash, completion

I'm looking for an easy way to "inherit" Bash completion functions from a program into a script.

Say there's a program `foo` that provides its own Bash completion, such that `$ foo sub<TAB>` completes to `$ foo subcommand`.  Now I want to write a script `foo-extra` that takes the same arguments as `foo`, doing some extra stuff before calling `foo <arguments>`.  What's the easiest way to make the `foo-extra` script piggy-back on `foo`'s completion function?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `foo` completes using a certain function (if standard, it would be usually defined in `/usr/share/bash-completion/completions/foo`, and possibly called something like `_foo`). The command that makes a function a completion function is:

```
complete -F _foo foo
```

You can co-opt the same function to an arbitrary command:

```
source /usr/share/bash-completion/completions/foo
complete -F _foo foo-extra
```

Comment: I actually needed a solution for ZSH, but I asked for Bash because it is a more common shell.  For reference, I got this to work using ZSH's version of the `complete` command called `compdef`: `compdef _foo foo-extra`  Thanks for your helpful answer though, it answered my question perfectly.

Comment: Sadly, I don't see a way to say "complete foo-extra as foo" without knowing what foo's completion function is. `complete -p foo` tells me, but only after it has been loaded, therefore it's unsafe to run `$(complete -p foo |awk '{$NF="foo-extra";print}')` (which will give you `bash: complete: foo: no completion specification`)